# The longest sequence of the same value, C, array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I need to find in an array the longest sequence of the same value, and return the length of this sequence. For instance, for `int tab[] = {2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3};` the answer should be `3` because we have here three fours. However, my code always returns 0, and I have no clue why:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int longest_sequence(int *tab, int n)
{
    int previous_len = 0, len = 0;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(tab[i+1] == tab[i])
        {
            len ++;
            if (len > previous_len)
            {
                previous_len = len;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            previous_len = len;
            len = 0;
        }
    }
    return len;
}

int main()
{
    int tab[] = {2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3};
    int n = 9;

    int res = longest_sequence(tab, n);
    printf("%d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Changed some errors as suggested in comments, however, the result is now 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int longest_sequence(int *tab, int n)
{
    int previous_len = 1, len = 1;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        if(tab[i+1] == tab[i])
        {
            len ++;
            printf("len = %d\n", len);

            if (len > previous_len)
            {
                previous_len = len;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            previous_len = len;
            len = 1;
        }
    }
    return len;
}

int main()
{
    int tab[] = {2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3};
    int n = 9;

    int res = longest_sequence(tab, n);
    printf("%d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
It seems ok now :

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int longest_sequence(int *tab, int n)
{
    int previous_len = 1, len = 1, max = 0;
    int i;

    if(n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        {
            if(tab[i+1] == tab[i])
            {
                len ++;

                if (len > previous_len)
                {
                    previous_len = len;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                previous_len = len;
                len = 1;
            }

            if(len > max)
                max = len;
        }
        return max;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int tab[] = {2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3};
    int n = 11;

    int res = longest_sequence(tab, n);
    printf("%d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is an off-by-one error in your code. Can you find it?

Comment: @FUZxxl: There are at least two off-by-one errors in the code, but I see only one out-of-bounds access...

Comment: I think I can, it should be `for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)` but it does not change anything. Am I right?

Comment: Please explain "*it does not change anything*", now it wouldn't be accessing the `tab[n]` element which is not one of the elements of your array.

Comment: @yak: How long is a sequence of 1 number?

Comment: I mean, it does not have the influence on the result, I still have 0 as the answer

Comment: But you have `0` because you return `0`, please check the logic in your code.

Comment: @EOF: I guess it's just `1`, ok, changed it to `int previous_len = 1, len = 1;` but now have `1`.

Comment: Returning `len` will return the length of the last sequence, not the longest one.   Also, if `n == 0`, presumably you do not want to return `1`.

Comment: @Peter : thank you. Is it ok now? It seems so, it returns 4 as expected.

Comment: @yak You selected a wrong answer with a bug.:) The best answer is obviously mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t longest_sequence( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    size_t len = 0;

    for ( const int *p = a; p != a + n; )
    {
        const int *q = p++;
        while ( p != a + n && *p == *q ) ++p;
        if ( len < ( size_t )( p - q ) ) len = p - q;
    }        

    return len;
}    

int main( void ) 
{
    int tab[] = { 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( tab ) / sizeof( *tab );

    size_t len = longest_sequence( tab, N );

    printf( "%zu\n", len );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3
```

Take into account that as usual my solution is the best among presented here.:)

Comment: @yak This answer does correctly handle the case of the popular number being all at the end, unlike the accepted answer.

Comment: Who ever said "*Humility is the strongest test of character...*" I like it!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It was boring to sit there without communication.:)

Answer (score 2):

You should increase a counter variable while the current value equals the next value, and then when the condition is false, you should check the length of the sequence against another variable where you store the length of the longest sequence, if it's less than the new length assign to it the new value, reset the current sequence length and continue, otherwise simply reset the current sequence length and continue

```
int
longest_sequence(int *array, int count)
{
    int length;
    int longest;
    longest = length = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < count - 1 ; i++)
    {
        if (array[i + 1] == array[i])
            length++;
        else
        {
             // length + 1 to count the last element too
            if (longest < length + 1)
                longest = length + 1;
            length = 0;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}

int
main()
{
    int array[] = {2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 3};
    int count = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    printf("The longest sequence has `%d' elements.\n", 
        longest_sequence(array, count));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fails with `{ 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 }`

Answer (score 0):

There are at leat these problems in your code:

```
 else
 {
    if (len > previous_len) // <<<< you are missing this test
      previous_len = len;

    len = 1;
 }
    return previous_len;    // <<<< return previous_len instead of len
```